# How to create C# Event to handle MFC Windows message from PostMessage()

Tags: c#, visual-c++, postmessage, cwnd, mfc-networking

I have a managed C++ DLL using WINSOCK.  On receive it sends a custom message to a CWnd * via PostMessage().  This works fine when called from unmanaged C++.  The target CWnd * is registered with the C++ class after construction using this code:

```
// Registers a window (CWnd *) to receive a message when a valid
// incoming data packet is received on this UdpRetrySocket. 
void CUdpRetrySocket::RegOnReceive(CWnd *i_pOnReceiveWnd, UINT i_RecvMsgId = WM_USER_RECV_DATA_AVAIL)
{
    m_pOnReceiveWnd = i_pOnReceiveWnd;
    m_RecvMsgId = i_RecvMsgId;
}
```

Here's the code that Posts the message to CWnd *

```
// If there is a pending incoming packet and there is a window
// registered for receive notification then post a message to it.
if (m_bInPktPending && m_pOnReceiveWnd != NULL)
    m_pOnReceiveWnd->PostMessage(m_RecvMsgId,
                                 (WPARAM)m_RecvSocket.LocalSockAddrIn().Port(),
                                 (LPARAM)this
                                );
```

I'm now using this CUdpRetrySocket class from a C# Windows Forms application. 
Questions:

1. From C# Forms class how do I obtain a CWnd * to register with my C++ CUdpRetrySocket class

   [FOUND ANSWER #1 HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/bdfb2783-4111-4ebf-b9ed-218200c09d03)

> ```
> // C++ Register Window Method
> void RegOnReceive(System::IntPtr i_Hwnd)
>    { m_pOnReceiveWnd = CWnd::FromHandle((HWND)i_Hwnd.ToPointer()); }
>
> // C# Caller of Register Window Method
> class MyForm : Form
> {
>     . . .
>     cmdDev.RegOnReceive(Handle);
> ```

1. How do I create an event in my C# window to capture this custom MFC style message?
2. I need the C# app to process packets even when window is minimized.  Will the C# Forms Window still receive these messages if it is minimized?
3. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer to how to create event handler [HERE](http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-341896.html)
You simply override the Form.WndProc() virtual method, test for the specific custom message ID and pass all others on to the base class for processing.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message message)
{
    if (message.Msg == MY_CUSTOM_WINDOW_MSG_ID)
    {
        // PROCESS EVENT HERE
    }            
    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Testing shows that the answer to the last question is YES.  The message is sent and processed even when Form is minimized.